# Update database table using ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have HTML page which contains a Editable table, Where I am fetching the data from database using PHP and inserting into the that table. As my table is Editable, I want to update the values into the database when the user update any row value.

Please suggest me,because I don't know how to make AJAX call when user edits and click anywhere on browser.

Comment: You should learn the ajax to implement this because no other option.

Comment: @Karthick. Any other suggestion ?

Comment: No buddy. Without ajax you cannot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I call ajax() when user enter(using keyboard) on input box using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24567950/how-do-i-call-ajax-when-user-enterusing-keyboard-on-input-box-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to catch the moment where the datas are saved in your datatable: Often a click on a button.
So you need a code like that :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#save-row-4').on('click', function(){
   // Your ajax call here
 });
});
```

The ajax have to be like :

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/php/script.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
       variable1: 'val1',
       variable2: 'val2',
       variable3: 'val3'
    },
    error: function(return) {
        alert("error");
    },
    success: function(return) {
        console.log("Datas saved");
    },
});
```

Don't forget to replace val1, val2 with the value of your inputs. Then, in your php script, you will be able to get these datas with $_POST['variable1'] .

Comment: Thanks a lot. That solves my problem. I got idea to proceed

Comment: No problems :-)