# removeEventListener onfocusout after pressing enter on input tag - error undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This is the first javascript I'm properly attempting.

What I'm trying to achieve:

- user focuses on input element and data from attributes get stored in variables
- `keyup` event listener added to input element
- when user presses enter, the value is sent via ajax to database
- once enter key pressed remove event listener

**Note:** The id of the input element is created dynamically with php, thus the reason for `update(this.id)`.

My *problem* is that an error shows when I focus on the element and I don't think the `removeEventListener()` `handler` argument is matching the `addEventListener()`, is that the correct way to match the same handler to the one used in `addEventListener`?

In [this](http://javascript.info/introduction-browser-events#addeventlistener) article it says

> Please note – if we don’t store the function in a variable, then we can’t remove it.

That's why I put the `handler` argument in the `enter()` function.

Any help is most appreciated!

Other links:
[Call Ajax when enter key pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24567950/how-do-i-call-ajax-when-user-enterusing-keyboard-on-input-box-using-jquery) 
[removeEventListener documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

JavaScript:

```js
function enter() {
    function(event) {
        console.log("Key has been released")
        event.preventDefault()
        //in the event of the user releasing 'ENTER' on the keyboard
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            console.log("'ENTER' key pressed")
            //creates variable to store the value of the element (attribute 'value', of input element: value='". $row['may'] .""')
            var inputValue = input.value
            // alert(input.value)
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'php script/update_values.php',
                dataType: "json",
                async:false,
                data: {id : id, input : inputValue, owner : owner, monthName : monthName},
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response.ajaxResponse)
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
//onfocus calls function with id='x' in contstructor to update score
function update(x) {
    console.log("User focused on input element.")
    //variable to assign the input element being updated 
    var input = document.getElementById(x)
    //store data in variables to be sent to script
    var id = input.getAttribute("data-id")
    var owner = input.getAttribute("data-owner")
    var monthName = input.getAttribute("data-monthName")

    //add an event listener to the input element (if a key is released executes 'function(event)')
    input.addEventListener("keyup", enter)
    input.removeEventListener("keyup", enter)

}
```

```html
<input id="1" onfocus="update(this.id)" data-reference="1" data-owner="Joe Bloggs" data-monthName="dec" data-monthValue="" type="" value="220000"/>
```

Comment: Fix your syntax

Comment: Are you sure you understand what you're doing? You are trying to add an event listener and remove it right after adding it, which doesn't make sense. What are you trying to do in the first place?

Comment: Also you can't just have `function(event)` unless  assigning to something, which you are not... you also never execute it.

Comment: @GuillaumeGeorges My intention was for the removeEventListener to execute once the user presses the enter key, I'm not entirely sure how to go about that, any advice is appreciated.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Originally it was assigned to the addEventListener handler argument and though it would work in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all doesn't make sense define a function inside another and not call anywhere. Also if it is a anonymous function. But I think you were confused with the sentence `if we don’t store the function in a variable, then we can’t remove it.`

In your case you add a handler function in your eventListener. If you immediately remove the listener it doesn't have any effect. SO maybe what you want to do is remove the listener handler once it is called. Once in the handler function your first parameter is the event object itself so you can access the target element. Then from there you can remove the listener.

```js
function enter(event) {

        console.log("Key has been released")
        event.preventDefault()
        //in the event of the user releasing 'ENTER' on the keyboard
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            console.log("'ENTER' key pressed")
            //creates variable to store the value of the element (attribute 'value', of input element: value='". $row['may'] .""')
            input = event.target;
            
            // alert(input.value)
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'php script/update_values.php',
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                data: {
                    id: input.id,
                    input: input.value,
                    owner: input.dataset.owner,
                    monthName: input.dataset.monthName
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response.ajaxResponse)
                }
            });
        }
    input.removeEventListener("keyup", enter)
}
//onfocus calls function with id='x' in contstructor to update score
function update(input) {
    console.log("User focused on input element.", input)
    //variable to assign the input element being updated 
    
    //store data in variables to be sent to script
    var id = input.getAttribute("data-id")
    var owner = input.getAttribute("data-owner")
    var monthName = input.getAttribute("data-monthName")

    //add an event listener to the input element (if a key is released executes 'function(event)')
    input.addEventListener("keyup", enter)


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="1" onfocus="update(this)" data-reference="1" data-owner="Joe Bloggs" data-monthName="dec" data-monthValue="" type="" value="220000"/>
```

Comment: You've got an uncaught error when pressing a key while focused on the field : "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: input is not defined"

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes a lot more sense! However I can't figure out why it's throwing an error on the 'input = even.target;', does that mean it can't access the target element?

Comment: In your comment you mispelled event , maybe is this the error?

Comment: the error is thrown when trying to remove the event listener. Because when the pressed key is not enter, the input variable is not defined. It's defined (without the var keyword, which is bad) in the `if (event.keyCode === 13) ` block

Comment: @GuillaumeGeorges Thank you, that's incredibly helpful! This works well for me, although Alex's answer was a lot clearer than my original code, jmtalam understood that I need the target element to be general in a sense and not as specific as "let input = document.querySelector('#myInput');", therefore marking this as answered and up voting Alex's answer (when I have enough reputation).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you are doing this the way you are since it's very messy but here's my input.

I separated handlers and events so I can remove them later.

---

```js
let input = document.querySelector('#myInput');
let id, owner, monthName;

let keyupHandler = e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (e.keyCode === 13) { // Enter key
    let inputValue = input.value;

    console.log(`Enter pressed.\nInput value: ${inputValue}\nProceeding AJAX call.`);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'php script/update_values.php',
      dataType: "json",
      async: true, // asyn: false = deprecated
      data: {
        id: id,
        input: inputValue,
        owner: owner,
        monthName: monthName
      },
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response.ajaxResponse);
        input.removeEventListener('keyup', keyupHandler);
        console.log("Removed keyup event");
      },
      error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        input.removeEventListener('keyup', keyupHandler);
        console.log("Removed keyup event");
      }
    });
  }
}

let focusHandler = e => {
  id = input.getAttribute("data-id")
  owner = input.getAttribute("data-owner")
  monthName = input.getAttribute("data-monthName")
  console.log(`Stored Data.\ndata-id: ${id}\ndata-owner: ${owner}\ndata-monthName: ${monthName}`);

  input.removeEventListener('focus', focusHandler);
  console.log("Removed focus event");
}

input.addEventListener('focus', focusHandler);

input.addEventListener('keyup', keyupHandler);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="myInput" data-id="1" data-reference="1" data-owner="Joe Bloggs" data-monthName="dec" data-monthValue="" type="" value="220000" />
```

Comment: @cookies you're very welcome. Make sure to select best answer to not keep it hanging :)